# Does Amazon AWS block multiple connection from the same IP?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, mysql, amazon-ec2

I use Amazon AWS, however, I am noticing a problem.  I have a machine I host outside of AWS which needs to make multiple connections to a database located within AWS.  It needs to make several queries which can lead up to 12 connections from the same IP to the database hosted on AWS.  That being said, I am noticing a lot of delay between queries when they should be executed right then and there.

This started occurring when I moved to AWS, and I haven't changed anything besides moving to AWS.

Any suggestions / help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, Amazon does not block multiple connections into EC2 from the same IP. The system functions just like any other TCP/IP v4 network and I can successfully open up hundreds of connections from one IP. Anyway your symptoms of "delay" wouldn't match up with your question about "blocking". You should look into software configuration issues on your machine. What kind of load is it experiencing? What does `netstat` show? Can you profile your database queries to see what part of the operation is taking extra time?